# Is there an email address that I can contact if I want to complain about MAS?

Tags: malaysia-airlines

For the moment I'm based in Malaysia.

I was trying to get my MAS flight time changed due to some unforeseen circumstances.

But the telephone line on [their website](http://www.malaysiaairlines.com/my/en/contact.html/) is simply frustrating to get through. I called many many times, being diverted here and there and in the end, still couldn't reach an operator.

I would want to launch a complaint against MAS, but I couldn't find any email address on their website. So is there anyway to get my voice heard?

Comment: Where are you based?  Malaysia has multiple phone numbers at most of their offices.  They have online forms you can submit to contact them.  They have Twitter and Facebook that you can send messages through.

Comment: I am aware of multiple phone numbers, but they all responded the same. I have just submitted my complaint via online forms, but my experience in dealing with online forms tells me not to put too much hope on it

Comment: @Tom, I'm based in Malaysia

Comment: My experience with MH was quite different. They answered the phone in 5-10 minute and their Twitter handler was very active too.

Answer (score 5):

From Malaysia Airlines [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/malaysiaairlines) [feedback](https://www.facebook.com/notes/malaysia-airlines/malaysia-airlines-facebook-house-rules/623123264386910/) page:

> We also encourage the use of the following channels for a more
>   efficient response to any comments related to service or flight
>   enquiries. Enrich : **enrich@malaysiaairlines.com** Social Media, Facebook
>   and Twitter : **socialmedia.team@malaysiaairlines.com** Twitter :
>   http://twitter.com/mas

From their [contact page](http://www.malaysiaairlines.com/my/en/contact.html/) that you link to, you may also fill in a web form as well as call any of their international numbers. For example, you may select the US/New York office to see the US toll free number and call that for free over skype or other VOIP service.

Alternative [facebook link](https://www.facebook.com/anz.malaysiaairlines/app/208195102528120) referring to the same email addresses without mentioning Singapore.

Comment: I scrolled through the MAS facebook page, and the feedback page, but couldn't find the email addresses you listed?

Comment: Sorry, put the wrong link under "feedback". Have fixed it now. Should point here: https://www.facebook.com/notes/malaysia-airlines/malaysia-airlines-facebook-house-rules/623123264386910/

Comment: "The Malaysia Airlines Singapore page is managed and monitored by our Social Media team based in Singapore"... but I am based in Malaysia

Comment: Many global companies have teams in different locations to deal with various issues. Does it matter where someone physically is if they're replying by email or social media?

Comment: I hope that you are right and the team based in Singapore can really take quick action

Comment: Added another link to another facebook page